# Count the number of times of component replacement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, logic, mysql-workbench

I want to find the count on "The number of times a replacement occurred for each component."

For example,

```
Component_ID | Replacement_ID
001          |    NULL
002          |     001
003          |     002
004          |     003
005          |     Null
```

Result :

```
Component_ID | Number of time a replacement already occurred
   004       |    3
   005       |    0
```

Comment: sounds like you need recursive logic for this.

Comment: will it help if i have a stored procedure  or function?

Comment: @momoni: Are the ID's in both columns are unique?

Comment: @zarruq replacement_id  is a old component_ID . yes it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you are supposed to have at-least two tables. A **components** table which contains your components with **Component_ID** as the primary field together with other fields such as **component_name** and another table probably called **component_replacements** which contains a primary field ID such as **component_replacement_id** together with **component_id** and other fields such as replacement date. **Component_ids** can occur more than once in this table. This would allow you to have a basic query such as:

```
SELECT Component_ID, IFNULL( total,0) replacements FROM
            (
              SELECT Component_ID, COUNT(*) total
                   FROM component_replacements GROUP BY Component_ID
            ) replacements ON components.Component_ID = replacements.Component_ID
```

Comment: i only have 1 table .. is it possible to do a if loop or while loop?

Comment: You want to do a loop so that you can COUNT. That's exactly why a GROUP By clause is there in SQL so that you don't have to do such things. If you can, it will be easy if you design your database in a way that allows you to answer such questions. Remember, a database is not only for storage, it should also provide reports and answers to your questions about the data it contains :)